# How to make custom error message in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

need make custom error message in Django Admin

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
email = instance.email
if User.objects.filter(email = email):
  if email == None:raise ValidationError('The email can not be null.')
  raise ValidationError('The email address is alerady in use.')
```

Comment: It is showing ValidationError why?

Comment: `User.objects.filter(email = email).exists()`

Comment: @KlausD.  But the problem is it is not showing the error message it is giving error ValidationError

Comment: yeah because you have `raise ValidationError()` in your code its an exception, why do you use ValidationError ? have you read through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/exceptions/#ValidationError) to know what it return ?